# База данных с календарем

Tags: mysql

Создаю базу данных по экскурсиям. Для каждой экскурсии нужно прописать календарные даты ее проведения так, чтобы на сайт можно было вывести к экскурсии ее даты и осуществлять поиск по дате (вывод интротекста всех экскурсий, входящих в заданный период). Имеет смысл создавать отдельную таблицу с календарем? Если да, то какой  структурой она должна обладать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Поиск по определенному диапазону дат возможен и по общей таблице с событиями (экскурсиями). Предположим, что таблица называется `excursion`, поле с интротекстом - `intro`, а поле с датой - `date_field` типа `TIMESTAMP`. Тогда запрос на выборку будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
SELECT `intro`
FROM `excursion`
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2016-05-28 21:29:06' AND '2016-05-29 12:21:25')
```

Я не вижу смысла создавать для этого отдельную таблицу.
Не забудьте повесить индекс на поле с датой.